# Unknown error while uploading file with help PHP

Tags: php, upload

If upload file with size 20-22MB all it`s ok. Upload 100% success.

But, if I try upload file with size 50MB, upload process stopping after 17-20-22-24MB (random) without any errors, I see this MBs in Inspect element -> Network - "Transferred"

PHP(5.6) setting in cPanel and in .php.ini and in **phpinfo();** is a same:

```
session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440
max_input_time = -1
max_execution_time = -1
upload_max_filesize = 128M
post_max_size = 265M
memory_limit = 2G
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Upload your files</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="POST">
    <p>Upload your file</p>
    <input type="file" name="uploaded_file"></input><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload"></input>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

upload.php:

```
<?PHP
  if(!empty($_FILES['uploaded_file']))
  {
    $path = "";
    $path = $path . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $path)) {
      echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']). 
      " has been uploaded";
    } else{
        echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
    }
  }
?>
```

How to check why not uploading?

Comment: Have you restart server?

Comment: No. I already writed ticket for hosting, but I think, that support does not know more about this issue, than I do. :(

Comment: Now I talk with support, about restart server...

Comment: If `phpinfo()` returns the correct values and you didn't run it from the command line, there's no need to restart the server.

Comment: Yes, **phpinfo()** returns the correct values.

Comment: have you checked the server error logs?

Comment: In cPanel -> errors: No any errors about this problem, or errors with my IP

Answer (score 0):

Maybe need increase memory_limit option?

Comment: Sorry, added in first post: memory_limit = 2G

Comment: What contains in variable $_SERVER['CONTENT_LENGTH']?